# Python doesnt imports matplotlib, matplotlib doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

So i searched a lot, but i am not able to solve the problem. Everytime i try to use matplotlib or similar (matplotlib.something), python isn't able to import it. It says:

```
  File "C:\Users\Privacy\ArduConnect.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\Privacy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\Privacy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Privacy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\Privacy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\Privacy\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: "A link to tinyurl but stackoverflow blocks it"
```

I already installed matplotlib. Do i have to reinstall Numpy? And how exactly?
Thank you for the support.

Comment: did you read the link?  it tells you exactly what to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem, you can fix it with:

```
pip uninstall pandas
python -m pip install numpy==1.19.3
pip install pandas
```

From [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) Microsoft thread fix will be available around January 2021.
Thanks.

Comment: There is a newer Version of numpy [1.19.4]. Shouldn't i install the newer one?

Comment: the newer version has the problem that you mentioned but as I said it will be fixed around January 2021.
Have Fun

Answer (score -1):

I think you should update those modules by

```
pip install <modulename> --update
Eg: pip install matplotlib --update
```

Comment: I did, but still not working.

Comment: Just do it for all modules and one thing I need to know which editor or IDE are u using?